# Maintain State on Server or in Hidden Fields?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have 20 items of the same type in a database.  Each of the items has a row ID, name, description, and section (A or B).

I have a web page that displays this information and allows the user to change the section attribute for each item.  The web page display has a pane for each of the two sections, section A and section B, and each section contains a button and a hidden field for each item in that section.  A button's label text is the item's name.  The hidden field is used to capture the corresponding item button's section (A or B).

When the user presses one of the item buttons in the section A pane, the button is moved to the section B pane and the button's hidden field is updated to 'B'.
Likewise, when the user presses one of the item buttons in the section B pane, the button is moved to the section A pane and the button's hidden field is updated to 'A'.

At the bottom of the form is a submit button.  When the submit button is pressed, all 20 hidden fields containing their associated button's section (A or B) are posted and the php server-side script updates the database for each button accordingly.

In such a case, is it best practice to use AJAX to maintain the state of the items on the server or hidden fields coupled with pure client-side javascript to maintain the state of the items prior to the form post?  Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to use AJAX to move buttons on the page? That's not what AJAX does. You use AJAX to communicate with the server.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas To persist the state, I think he/she means.

Comment: I edited the question to ask how to persist the state.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's better user experience to use AJAX and update the section.  This saves the user from having to click the submit button after all selections have been made.  Also, much simpler because you don't need to store these prior states in a hidden field or in session. You can just do the update in real time.

Comment: I agree with you.  Our prototype for our customer used this methodology, however the customer wants a batch submit button in the final build instead.

Comment: "Do what the customer wants" is always the correct answer. However, don't throw away your prototype, because once the customer gets what he wants and finds it not as good as he thought, he may come round to doing things your way.